# Xcode won't build due to Framework not found

Tags: swift, xcode

FYI - I'm a novice with Xcode.

I'm running Xcode on MacBook Pro High Sierra OS only to make minor amendments to a simple app. I was given the project folder and manage to get the project running previously and make the minor changes and publish these to Apple. No problem at all.

I moved the project off my desktop a while back. I now have to make an update. I have moved the project back to my desktop and attempted to build the project but I'm now getting an error where a library cannot be found even though it is there and is being referenced in the correct location. I don't think it's anything to do with moving the project... Here's what I'm seeing...

[image: Xcode 9.2 issues output]

[image: Linked Frameworks and Librarys view]

I have tried to remove and add the offending library with no success.

Maybe it's a red herrin?

I am stuck... please help!!!!

Comment: check build paths

Comment: Can you give more details. I have check the build settings and these all point to the correct paths?

Answer (score 2):

This what worked for me:
1) Remove library from pod file.
2) Run "pod update"
3) Re-add library to podfile
4) Again do pod update
5) Do a clean build.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because previous reference of library is present at following path:

Target->Build settings->Search Paths->Library search path

Remove previous path from here and add new one.It will work

Comment: Nope it won't build settings are correct. Still getting the same error

Comment: Have you checked Library search path.Is it same to reference of of your framework

Comment: Hmmm. I copied the library from my original project to ensure it hadn't got corrupted. I now get a different message.

Comment: `ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/andyrh3/Desktop/Buchung/Librarys/DWHelperLibrary.framework/DWHelperLibrary, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 0x72 0x72 0x65 0x6E 0x74 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64):`

Comment: Does your framework is listed under linked libraries list under build settings?

Comment: Yes it is and I have tried to remove and re-add it and clean and rebuild with no success. I have the library accessible now since I copied it over from the original project backup, but I'm getting the architecture error now?

Comment: Have you set arm64 in valid architecture?

Comment: Yes my Valid architecture type includes arm64.